# AttributeError: 'SecondWindow' object has no attribute 'donkey'

Tags: python, kivy

main.py

```
def donkey():
    f = open("uni.txt", "a")
    f.write(college)
    f.close()


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

my.kv

```
<SecondWindow>:
name: "second"
GridLayout:
    cols:1
    size: root.width, root.height
    background_color: 1,.5,.3,1
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":.2, "top":.15}
            size_hint: .6, .05
            text: "Go Back"
            background_color: .1,.1,.1,1
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":.2, "top":.23}
            size_hint: .6, .05
            text: "Continue"
            background_color: .1,.1,.1,1
            on_release: root.donkey()

        Label:
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":.85}
            bold: True
            font: 24
            text: "Enter the name of the college"

        TextInput:
            id: college
            pos_hint: {"x":.15, "top":.82}
            size_hint: .7, .045
            multiline: False
```

I'm getting the error:
AttributeError: 'SecondWindow' object has no attribute 'donkey'

Donkey is just a function to write to a file, if someone could help me fix this error or a better way to read/write to a file

Comment: why did you pick the name `donkey` ? +1 for `donkey` (and also because this seems answerable by someone familiar with kivy)

Answer (score 1):

In your `kv` file, add:

```
#:import donkey main.donkey
```

and change:

```
on_release: root.donkey()
```

to:

```
on_release: donkey()
```

Comment: Once I do that I get this error:  AttributeError: module 'main' has no attribute 'donkey'

Comment: is your `py` file named `main.py`?

Comment: Yes it's named main.py

Comment: There must be something else going on. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Another simple solution is to leave your 'kv' file as original, and just move the `donkey` method inside the `SecondWindow` class.